# CheckBoxPreference not checking when clicking on it

Tags: android, android-preferences

Is it possible to make CheckBoxPreference not selecting by clicking on it but only programically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:selectable="false"` or `android:enabled="false"` in XML. Using `android:enabled="false"` also grays out the CheckBoxPreference. You can use `setEnabled()` or `setSelectable()` if you get CheckBoxPreference instance programmatically.